# get the id of a related field and save data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm kinda new to DRF, I am building a database for attendance. I want to save an instance of `AttendanceSlot` in my `Attendance` but I don't know how to get id, so i can save it...
models.py

```
class AttendanceSlot(models.Model):
    department_id = models.ForeignKey("students.Department", verbose_name=_("department id"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey("students.Course", verbose_name=_("course id"), related_name= 'course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lecturer_id = models.ForeignKey("lecturers.Lecturer", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(_("attendance date"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    start_time = models.TimeField(_("start time"), auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    longitude = models.CharField(_("longitude"), max_length=50)
    latitude = models.CharField(_("latitude"), max_length=50)
    radius = models.CharField(_("radius"), max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(self.course_id.course_code)

class Attendance(models.Model):
    slot_id = models.ForeignKey("attendance.AttendanceSlot", verbose_name=_("attendance slot"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student_id = models.ForeignKey("students.Student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    performance = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

serializers.py

```
class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # student_id = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True)
    slot_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=AttendanceSlot.objects.all(), many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['student_id', 'slot_id', 'performance']
```

views.py

```
class Attendance(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Attendance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        id = self.kwargs['pk']
        slot = AttendanceSlot.objects.get(id=id)
        return slot

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user = self.request.user, slot_id=self.get_queryset())
        return super().perform_create(serializer)
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.Attendance.as_view(), name='attendance'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are not receiving the `slot_id` from the request but getting it from the database. So you don't even need to specify the `slot_id` in your serializer. So change your `views.py` and `serializers.py` files like these

```py
# views.py
class Attendance(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Attendance.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AttendanceSerializer
```

and

```py
# serializers.py
class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ['student_id',  'performance']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        slot_id = self.context['view'].kwargs['pk']
        slot = AttendanceSlot.objects.get(id=slot_id)
        return Attendance.objects.create(slot=slot, **validated_data)
```

**Note:** The above serializer is expecting that you will pass `student_id` and `performance` in the body of your `POST` request.

Comment: Thanks... This worked... I've modified it to automatically add logged in user.